Elasticsearch query with regex for digits is not working as expected
I have an index in elastic with field messages like this:
Start publishing 11 trade jobs...
Start publishing 123 trade jobs...
Start publishing trade jobs...

I want write a query to get all the values which match the following pattern:
Start publishing 11 trade jobs...
Start publishing 123 trade jobs...

Here are the queries that I have tried:
The following query returns no results:
GET my-logs-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message": "Start publishing [0-9]+ trade jobs..."
    }
  }
}

And this one has a syntax error (Bad String) according to the console:
GET my-logs-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message": "Start publishing \d+ trade jobs\.\.\."
    }
  }
}

And the last one is:
GET my-logs-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message.keyword": "Start publishing.*trade jobs"
    }
  }
}

But the strangest thing is that this last query return logs with this pattern "Start publishing trade jobs".
How can I fix my problem?

"Start publishing \d+ trade jobs\.\.\." must be "Start publishing [0-9]+ trade jobs\\.\\.\\.", but it won't work if "Start publishing [0-9]+ trade jobs..." does not. There is an issue not related to the regex itself.

@WiktorStribiżew thanks that actually works. I suppose the official documentation needs to be more clear on that.
